# making downloaded file not transferable in django

Tags: python, django, file, download

I am developing a bookstore app, I want to make downloaded files not shareable to other devices. which means users can not share files that are downloaded from the site. I tried searching different sites to know how I can make the file downloaded not shareable but I didn't get any solution. please help me with what can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: You can't unless you also build a software to process that file and implement DRM on it and the file.